# Dust - how to get parent context in loop

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I am trying to retrieve values in a loop from the parent context. Dust is able to call my method, but my method is not able to reach my properties which I have defined in the class, due to the context is the current item.

So for example:
**JavaScript class**

```
MyNamespace.MyClass = function () {
   this.names= ["Me", "You", "StackOverflow"];
   this.isAwesome = true;
};

MyNamespace.MyClass.prototype.sayHello = function() {
   if(this.isAwesome) {
      return "Hello awesome ";
      // This code will never be reached due to 'this' is one of the items from the array
   }
   return "Hello "; 
};
```

**My Dust**

```
{#names}{sayHello} {.}{~n}{/names}
```

**Problem**
The `sayHello` method will be called as expected **but** the context is the current item instead of the parent. So `this` is equals to the current item and of course `"Me".isAwesome` will always return false. As you would understand, I would like to be awesome.

**Question**
How can I achieve that 3 awesome people are returned by dust.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the required contextual variable as a parameter:

```
{#names myvar=parentContextVariable}{sayHello x=myvar} {.}{~n}{/names}
```

And then, in the helper function:

```
"sayHello": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    //use params.x
}
```

Yes, here also, your function will have the extra concern (of DustJs's presence).

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function using Dust, the function is invoked with the arguments `chunk, context, bodies, params`.

You can call `context.get(name)` to search the context stack for your desired variable.

```
{
  "sayHello": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    if(context.get("isAwesome")) {
      return "Hello awesome";
    }
    return "Hello";
  },
  "names": ["One", "Two", "Three"],
  "isAwesome": true
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. It works but this means that my model has to know that DUST is used for rendering. So my "sayHello" method has an extra concern.. Which means I am chained to DUST if I am going this approach.

Comment: This is mostly because Dust has a different model of context scope than vanilla Javascript, since you can have multiple hierarchical levels of scope and they are searched from bottom-up.